# How to slice sequences and get their frequencies in Numpy/Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I needed help writing code that broke apart a list of strings into a certain value, and then ran the frequency of each one in a grid like manner. For example:

```
a = ['ABGD','HDIW','ABHD']
b = ['AB','GD','HD','IW','AB','HD'] #breaking by two
#look something like this (please ignore periods):
AB   HD.  GD.  HD.   IW.   
2.   2.   1.   1.    1.
```

I would prefer this to be done in Numpy. Here is what I have so far, but the first part (where the list is being broken) only breaks the strings individually rather than a set value:

```
brk_str = [list(i) for i in a]
brk_arr = np.array(brk_str)
unique_elements, counts_elements = np.unique(brk_arr, return_counts=True)
print(np.asarray((unique_elements, counts_elements)))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add more details about how you create list b. Are your strings of fixed length (i.e 4)? If not how does the split happen? How does list b look like if all your strings are of odd  or mixed length?

Comment: Why do you prefer `numpy`?  The fast compiled numpy methods mostly work with numeric values, not strings.  `unique` works by sorting the array, and checking for adjacent duplicates.  Overall this looks more like a list task than an array one.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to break the strings into 2

```
In [753]: b = []
     ...: for word in a:
     ...:     b.extend([word[:2],word[2:]])
In [754]: b
Out[754]: ['AB', 'GD', 'HD', 'IW', 'AB', 'HD']
```

Splitting a string into pieces is a string operation.  `numpy` does not implement any special string methods itself.  Even the `np.char` functions use string methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double-for inside the list comprehension

```
brk_str = [x for i in a for x in (i[:2], i[2:])]
brk_arr = np.array([x for i in a for x in (i[:2], i[2:])])
unique_elements, counts_elements = np.unique(brk_arr, return_counts=True)
print(np.asarray((unique_elements, counts_elements)))

[['AB' 'GD' 'HD' 'IW']
 ['2' '1' '2' '1']]
```

The classic way to manipulate data with a given quantity is `collections.Counter`

```
c = Counter([x for i in a for x in (i[:2], i[2:])])
print(c)  # {'AB': 2, 'HD': 2, 'GD': 1, 'IW': 1}
```